# Where have I gone wrong with this custom React hook - useLocalStorage?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I'm trying to figure out whats wrong with my custom hook. I'm trying to add some products to local storage on a click event. The hook is working but its overriding itself when I switch to a new category.

I tried putting the hook into its own context but still get the same issues. I've re-created the problem in CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-water-kxml8?file=/src/App.js

Thanks in advance!
Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your useLocalStorage hook works as one would expect. But you are using it in multiple components at the same time with the same key. And it has not any logic to distribute the changes to other components.

The easiest Option is to move the useLocalStorage into App and pass the state and update to the components.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ian, yeah I can see where you're coming from. Would I be able to wrap the App with a context and provide the state and update to the components? Cheers

Comment: I think this should work. But I don't have much experience with context. Sorry

Comment: Yeah it works with context, just tried it then. Thanks for input!

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is with the `useEffect` dependency logic. When the `key` changes (switching to a new category) the `storedValue` is still the old value for the previous key, so it overwrites the new key with the old value.

I think if you create your own setter function you will have much greater control over what gets set in local storage.

```
function useLocalStorage(key) {
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(loadValue(key));

  useEffect(() => {
    setStoredValue(loadValue(key));
  }, [key]);

  const setValue = (value) => {
    setStoredValue(value);
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  };

  return [storedValue, setValue];
}

function loadValue(key) {
  const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
  return item ? JSON.parse(item) : [];
}
```

Comment: I think there is an extra brace at the end `const setValue = (value) => {
    setStoredValue(value);
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  });`

Comment: Thanks for the comment Teddy, I've changed the code around to your solutions but I'm still having the same issue.